# Django/SQL: what's most efficient, more columns or more tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, django

I have a MySQL database that I'm using with Django. One of my tables has around 60 columns. I'm wondering whether to split it into 5-6 smaller tables. This would make logical sense, since the columns split nicely into 5-6 logical groups.

The downside would be that some of the Django pages would then require 5-6 row queries instead of 1.

Is it more efficient to have one table with many columns, or many tables with fewer columns? If the former, how much of a disadvantage is it to have many tables? (as far as one can quantify such things...)

Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use old Opccams' razor. Do not do unnecessary moves. Are you okay with your one table? If so - leave it as is. Do not make yourself a trouble out of nowhere.
2. You are wrong about 6 queries. It will be still single query. But see item 1.

Comment: heh :) it's just a bit unwieldy having so many columns, but I suspect you might be right...

Comment: @AP257 unwieldy to whom? To database? I can assure you it can handle ten times more. To you? But there will be no difference when you get final result. Yes, the number seems quite big. But optimizing database structure is not just splitting tables. Make your database structure based on logical principles, not such err.. emotions

Answer (score 0):

If it's logical to split them into multiple models, then split them. Just for reason of efficiency, don't keep them in single model.

Performance/Effectiveness of retrieving data really depends on how you structure your query. No point loading all 70 columns in memory when you will be using only 5 - 10 fields. You can just select what you want using .values().

Also when you split into multiple models and using foreign keys to relate them, then using select_related you can retrieve same information with fewer queries and sometimes even 1.

If we can see model, may be we can give our best opinions.